# Pass spoken numerical value to function

Tags: python, python-dragonfly

I want to pass a spoken numerical value to a function, but I'm having problems casting that value to an integer.  I am only able to pass the string %(number)d to the foo function.

I've tried many different things to cast the spoken value to a number including int, float, and %(n)d.

```
def foo(slot):
    startingPoint = .15
    increment = .05
    calculation = (slot*increment)
    slotNumber = (startingPoint + calculation) - increment
    return "(0.1, {}), left".format(slotNumber)
```

```
class CodeMappings(MappingRule):
    mapping = {  
        'slot <number>': foo('%(number)d'),  
        'slot 1': Mouse("(0.1, 0.15), left"),  
        'slot 2': Mouse("(0.1, 0.2), left"),  
        'slot 3': Mouse("(0.1, 0.25), left"),  
        'Slot 4': Mouse("(0.1, 0.30), left"),  
        'Slot 5': Mouse("(0.1, 0.35), left"),  
        'Slot 6': Mouse("(0.1, 0.40), left"),  
        'Slot 7': Mouse("(0.1, 0.45), left"),  
        'Slot 8': Mouse("(0.1, 0.50), left"),          
    }
    extras=[
        Integer('number', 1, 9999),
    ]
```

I want to be able to send a spoken numeric value to the foo method and have it return the appropriate mouse coordination.  Essentially I should be able to write one method to replace the equivalent of slot 1 - slot 8.

Answer (score 1):

This question was answered on the dragonfly gitter channel by Mike Roberts.  Thanks Mike!

https://gitter.im/dictation-toolbox/dragonfly?source=orgpage

[image]